# Angular 2 router fails to reuse same Component instance when navigating to same route with different params

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

According to [the Angular 2 docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html):

> By default, the router reuses a component instance when it
>   re-navigates to the same component type without visiting a different
>   component first. The parameters can change between each re-use

I need help figuring out why this does not work on my lazy-loaded routes. To reproduce:

- [Open this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BCUlXdyUWpLMWuWO5do1?p=preview)
- On `LazyLoadedComponent` press `Next ID` button to trigger navigation to the same route (new param). Notice that the component is destroyed and a new instance is initialized each time.

[image]

- On `HomeComponent`, things work as expected. Triggering navigation executes the `ActivatedRoute.params.subscribe()` callback but the component is not re-initialized

[image]

I'm using `Angular 2 rc.5` and `Angular Router 3 rc.1` Why does my lazy-loaded component not behave in accordance with the docs?

Answer (score 1):

This is an Angular bug. It has been reported and the next version should be fixed. See https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/10707